Manhwa story about a guy who can learn anything by living another person's life
What I recall of the story is that the main character, is a guy who can learn anything by experiencing the lives of those who are skilled at it, be it the piano, violin, painting, or anything else. However, the unintended consequence would be that it would be challenging to determine which was his actual life. One scene I remember was that he learned piano to impress this beautiful black haired girl in a restaurant.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Was it colour or black-and-white?  How much of people's lives was it necessary to live to learn a skill?

The female protagonist version would be "A Capable Maid". I don't see any useful tags or recommendations on the tracking sites I use; I think recommendations don't often swap between male and female oriented stories.
